# iOS handling initial data sync which may take several minutes

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app that needs to sync a lot of data from the cloud to device when first installed, maybe even 2GB worth if the user wants access to everything offline.  Without saying "change your design", how can I ensure this initial sync completes without too much interaction from the user?

Currently it will complete as long as they keep my app in the foreground and don't let the device go to sleep.  I'd like to allow them to use other apps or let the screen turn off during this process, since it's a pretty boring thing to watch.

I've seen [application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:) and 
[beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:), but they only allow for a short amount of time (around 30 seconds) to complete a task.  Is there something better, or do I need to complicate my design by stopping my sync every ~25 seconds, and then resume next time I'm given more time by the OS?

My app is like Microsoft Outlook, it has emails (in some case millions), contacts, calendar, and several other areas.  I have different sync options to limit the amount of data, but some users want access to everything offline (yes, even emails and attachments that are 10 years old).  I think they are silly, but can't argue with the end-users.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but I suggest you use NSURLSession to download data in the background even without your app running.

You simply create an NSURLSession that uses a Background NSURLSessionConfiguration (use NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:)  and create an NSURLSessionDownloadTask for each request you need to download.

NSURLSession will download the data even when your app is not running at all, and it will save the data as files in your app's sandbox. Implement the NSURLSession delegate methods to receive notification of the download completion, read the downloaded files and save them how you see fit.

You should check out Apple's guide on [Using NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1).